# Importing Pyspark PipelineModel with custom transformers into Scala

Tags: python-3.x, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, pipeline

I recently created a pyspark PipelineModel with a few custom transformers to generate features not doable with the native Spark transformers. Here's an example of one of my transformers. It takes an string label input and returns a superclass label of the input:

```
class newLabelMap(
    Transformer, HasInputCol, HasOutputCol, DefaultParamsReadable, DefaultParamsWritable,
):
    inputCol = Param(Params._dummy(),"inputCol","The input column",TypeConverters.toString)
    outputCol = Param(Params._dummy(),"outputCol","The output column",TypeConverters.toString)

    def __init__(self, inputCol = "", outputCol=""):
        super(newLabelMap, self).__init__()
        self._setDefault(inputCol="")
        self._setDefault(outputCol="")
        self._set(inputCol=inputCol)
        self._set(outputCol=outputCol)


    def getInputCol(self):
        return self.getOrDefault(self.inputCol)

    def setInputCol(self, inputCol):
        self._set(inputCol=inputCol)

    def getOutputCol(self):
        return self.getOrDefault(self.outputCol)

    def setOutputCol(self, outputCol):
        self._set(outputCol=outputCol)

    def _transform(self, dataset):
        @udf("string")
        def findLabel(labelVal):
            new_label_dict = {'oldLabel0' : 'newLabel0',
                          'oldLabel1' : 'newLabel1',
                          'oldLabel2' : 'newLabel1',
                          'oldLabel3' : 'newLabel1',
                          'oldLabel4' : 'newLabel2',
                          'oldLabel5' : 'newLabel2',
                          'oldLabel6' : 'newLabel2',
                          'oldLabel7' : 'newLabel3',
                          'oldLabel8' : 'newLabel3',
                          'oldLabel9' : 'newLabel4',
                          'oldLabel10' : 'newLabel4'}

            try:
                labelKey = new_label_dict[labelVal]
                return labelKey
            except:
                return 'other'

        out_col = self.getOutputCol()
        in_col = dataset[self.getInputCol()]
        return dataset.withColumn(out_col, findLabel(in_col))
```

The transformer works fine in the Pipeline, I can save it, load it back into a pyspark session, and transform without any issue. The issue comes when I try to import it into a scala environment. When I try to load the model, I receive this error output:

```
Name: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Message: requirement failed: Error loading metadata: Expected class name org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel but found class name pyspark.ml.pipeline.PipelineModel
StackTrace:   at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.util.DefaultParamsReader$.parseMetadata(ReadWrite.scala:638)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.util.DefaultParamsReader$.loadMetadata(ReadWrite.scala:616)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline$SharedReadWrite$.load(Pipeline.scala:267)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel$PipelineModelReader.load(Pipeline.scala:348)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel$PipelineModelReader.load(Pipeline.scala:342)
```

If I remove the custom transformer, it loads just fine in Scala, so I'm curious how to be able to use custom transformers written in pyspark that can be ported in a PipelineModel to a Scala environment? Do I need to append my code in any way? Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Have you found a solution for this ? I am having the same issue